# bounded continuous functions

Tags: measure-theory

is it true that on $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ and assuming Borel $\sigma$ field, two finite positive measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ are the same iff $\int f \mathbb{d \mu} = \int f \mathbb{d \nu}$ for all bounded continuous functions $f$?

Comment: Those integrals don't necessarily exist. $\;$

Comment: you may add the restriction of non-negative to your bounded continuous functions

Comment: i edited it now, continuous functions are definitely measurable, and with the constraint of positive measure, they will exist

Comment: @Amr  non-negative won't be an issue if measures are finite

Comment: @user17523 yes. I did not notice it.

Comment: @Amr me too engineering grad student...wanted to study math as grad student but decent univs dont take engineering grads as math grads...ended up as engineering grad...but still end up doing some maths stuff :|

Comment: @user17523 great. I extremely  hate  education in engineering. We can discuss this on chat if you are interested. I think it is not appropriate to discuss it here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10694/discussion-between-user17523-and-amr)

Comment: I deleted my answer as I verified that Lusin's theorem was applicable. The finiteness of the measures ensures that they are regular and the theorem is indeed applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E$ be a measurable set and let $\chi_E$ be its characteristic function. By Lusin's theorem (See Rudin's Real & Complex Analysis, 2.24), there is a sequence of continuous functions with compact support $\{g_n\}$ such that $|g_n| \le 1$ and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} g_n(x) = \chi_E(x) \quad \text{[a.e.].}
$$

By applying the dominated convergence theorem to $\int g_n d\mu = \int g_n d\nu$, we get $\mu(E) = \nu(E)$.

We use the fact that $\mathbb R^N$  is locally compact and Hausdorff, as well as the finiteness of $\mu$, $\nu$ in order to apply the theorem.